# how to fire notification from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, methods, broadcastreceiver

how to fire notification from BroadcastReceiver (can't use most methods and can't use "this")?
I need it to open a activity with info from the DB I already did it but now must of the methods dosen't work and I cant use "this"

Answer (score 1):

In the `onReceive` method you get a `Context` object. So use it to get the `NotificationManager` and fire your notification.

```
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //Create the notification here.
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

An `Activity` and a `Service` are derived from `Context`. That's why, in many (or **all**) of the instance methods of a context, you can use `this`. If that's your case, then you can use the `Context` you receive in `onReceive`.

Comment: For my use case, what if there are hundreds of pendingIntents for triggering Alarms, that need to be reset after the BroadcastReceiver receives a BOOT_COMPLETED action?  Since there are many alarms how would I reset these alarms in the background?