# Class extending BroadcastReceiver can't display UI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-c2dm

I followed a tutorial online on how to receive push notifications on Android. Got everything set up on our server and was able to receive a message and log it.

The class that receives the message is called MessageReceiver and extends BroadcastReceiver. In this class's OnReceive() message I managed to Log.v the message payload correctly.

Now this OnReceive() is not able to do any UI stuff, like for example if I wanted to pop up a window telling the user that a push has come in, I couldn't. I can't even create a Notification from here to put in the phone's toolbar.

What should I do? I don't want to change my message receving code too much as it seems to be working ok. Any ideas on how I can get this method to interact with the UI or call other methods from other .java files? I know I could always create static methods and call them from here, but a lot of the methods I want to call would not work as static as they interact with many other pieces of code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link should answer your question.  Basically, use the Context in the onReceive method.

[Fire Notification from Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280275/how-to-fire-notification-from-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Strangely enough I didn't even realize that it was getting back a Context object. Also didn't realize that this question has already been asked and answered. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a Notification just fine from a BroadcastReceiver. If you want to really interact with the UI though, you should just start an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Recievers cant really affect UI.you need to use activity for that.